# Repeated methods call different properties of a model

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is it possible to simplify this code? I am transforming data from a list of values into the same Object. In each method the property being summed changes.

Properties follow the same naming convention every time (`paios` or `pa`) followed by (`InUse` or `SuportInUse`). I know in JavaScript I could generate the strings and eval the string, but as far as I know there is nothing similar in C#.

```
public class CompanyLicValues
{
    public int Paios;
    public int Papc;
    public int Paplus;
    public int Eis;
    public int Pd;
    public int Dropoff;

    public CompanyLicValues SumInUse(List<vwCompany> companies)
    {
        Paios = companies.Sum(x => x.paiosInUse); //<<<The property being summed changes
        Papc = companies.Sum(x => x.papcInUse); //<<<The property being summed changes
        ....
        return this;
    }

    public CompanyLicValues SumSupportUsed(List<vwCompany> companies)
    {
        Paios = companies.Sum(x => x.paiosSupportInUse); //<<<The property being summed changes
        Papc = companies.Sum(x => x.papcSupportInUse); //<<<The property being summed changes
        ...
        return this;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the property being summed changes"?

Comment: You could just use one function with another paramter that selects the property to be summed. Something along these lines: `public CompanyLicValues Sum(List<vwCompany> companies, Func<vwCompany, int> propSelector)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use reflection to get properties and then find the which one to use

```
public class CompanyLicValues
{
    public int Paios { get; private set; }
    public int Papc { get; private set; }


    public CompanyLicValues SumInUse(List<VwCompany> companies)
    {
        SumDynamically(companies, "InUse");
        return this; return this;
    }

    public CompanyLicValues SumSupportUsed(List<VwCompany> companies)
    {
        SumDynamically(companies, "SupportInUse");
        return this;
    }

    private void SumDynamically(IReadOnlyCollection<VwCompany> companies, string propertySuffix)
    {
        Paios = SumProperty(companies, $"{nameof(Paios)}{propertySuffix}");
        Papc = SumProperty(companies, $"{nameof(Papc)}{propertySuffix}");
    }

    private static int SumProperty(IEnumerable<VwCompany> companies, string propertyName)
    {
        var properties = typeof(VwCompany).GetProperties(); //cache properties
        var p = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName && x.GetMethod.ReturnType == typeof(int));
        if (p is null) throw new Exception("Property Not found");

        return companies.Sum(x => (int)p.GetValue(x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your classes to use Properties instead of Fields as that offers greater flexibility in future as you can customize getter/setter logic. As well as making the setters `private` or `internal` allowing you to return a read-only view of your data.

For your problem you'll want to use Linq's `Aggregate` extension method, but provide a custom accumulator based on reflection, like so:

```
public class GenericAccumulator<TAccumulator,TItem>
{
    private readonly TAccumulator accumulator;

    private readonly IReadOnlyList<(PropertyInfo itemProperty, PropertyInfo accumulatorProperty)> propertyMap;

    public GenericAccumulator( TAccumulator accumulator )
    {
        this.accumulator = accumulator;

        PropertyInfo[] accumulatorProperties = typeof(TAccumulator).GetProperties();

        Dictionary<String,PropertyInfo> itemPropertiesByName = typeof(TItem)
            .GetProperties()
            .ToDictionary( pi => pi.Name );

        List<(PropertyInfo itemProperty, PropertyInfo accumulatorProperty)> itemProperties = new List<(PropertyInfo itemProperty, PropertyInfo accumulatorProperty)>();

        foreach( PropertyInfo accumulatorProperty in accumulatorProperties )
        {
            String expectedItemPropertyName = accumulatorProperty.Name + "InUse";
            if( itemPropertiesByName.TryGetValue( expectedItemPropertyName, out PropertyInfo itemProperty )
            {
                itemProperties.Add( ( itemProperty, accumulatorProperty ) );
            }
        }

        this.propertyMap = itemProperties;
    }

    public GenericAccumulator<TAccumulator,TItem> Next( GenericAccumulator<TAccumulator,TItem> self, TItem item )
    {
        // Ignore `self`. It's needed for compatibility with Linq's `Func` parameter.

        foreach( PropertyInfo itemProperty in this.itemProperties )
        {
            PropertyInfo accumulatorProperty = this.propertyMap[ itemProperty ];

            Int32 itemPropertyValue        = (Int32)itemProperty.GetValue( item, null );
            Int32 accumulatorPropertyValue = (Int32)accumulatorProperty.GetValue( this.accumulator, null );

            accumulatorPropertyValue += itemPropertyValue;

            accumulatorProperty.SetValue( this.accumulator, null, accumulatorPropertyValue );
        }
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
using System.Linq;

class CompanyLicenseAccumulator
{
    public Int32 Paios  { get; set; }
    public Int32 Papc   { get; set; }
    public Int32 Paplus { get; set; }
    // etc
}

static void Foo()
{
    List<vwCompany> companies = ...

    GenericAccumulator<CompanyLicenseAccumulator,CompanyLicense> ca = new GenericAccumulator<CompanyLicenseAccumulator,CompanyLicense>( new CompanyLicenseAccumulator() );

    CompanyLicenseAccumulator summedValues = companies
        .Aggregate( ca ), ca.Next );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CompanyLicValues
{
    private List<vwCompany>  _companies;
    public CompanyLicValues(List<vwCompany> companies)
    {
    _companies=companies;
    }
    public int  Paios
    {
    return _companies.Sum(x => x.paiosInUse); 
    }
    public int  Papc
    {
    return _companies.Sum(x => x.papcInUse); 
    }   
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class CompanyLicValues
    {

 List<vwCompany>  _companies;
        public CompanyLicValues(List<vwCompany> companies)
        {
        _companies=companies;
        }
        public int  Paios
        {
        return companies.Sum(x => x.paiosInUse); 
        }
        public int  Papc
        {
        return companies.Sum(x => x.papcInUse); 
        }   
    }
```

Try this